# SAP Vora 1.4 worker stopped

Tags: vora

I'm running Vora 1.4 on a Centos 7.5 single node.
The installation was fine, and I can access the Vora Manager.

However the Vora Worker always stops. Here is what I see in `/var/log/vora/vora-manager/vora-manager.log`:

> ```
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Stopping
>     component due to task status. #012Service task scheduler-client status is 1
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Stopping due to
>     waitfortasks error.
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Stopping component
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Stopping service 
>     registration schemes
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Stopping tasks
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1][task-scheduler-client] :
>     Killing task: scheduler-client pid: 12298
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1][task-scheduler-client] : Killed
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Deleting running path
> May 7 22:47:29 centos vora.vora-manager-worker: [c.92eecff1] : Component stopped
> ```

Some advise would be great.
Cheers
Gerd

Answer (score 0):

The log entries seem to be unrelated to the failing VoraMgr worker - they actually show that it was working when those entries were created. The Vora Manager Worker should start a 'nomad' process. Could you check if this process is still running? If not, could you try to manually start it:

```
/opt/vora/lib/vora-scheduler/bin/nomad agent -config /etc/vora/vora-scheduler/client_config.json
```

If this fails, please check if the error is covered in the [Vora 1.4 Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/347253ce050e484eb3277a46d290fb92/1.4/en-US/SAP_Vora_Troubleshooting_Guide_1.4_en.pdf).

Also could you please share your Hadoop distribution + version and Vora 1.4 version.

Vora 1.4 is rather old by now. I would strongly recommend upgrading to a current version such as Vora 2.1 or DataHub 1.3. Please be aware that in those current versions the deployment model has changed - the installation is now in a Kubernetes cluster instead of installing Vora alongside the Hadoop nodes. There is no more Vora Manager.

- https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_VORA
- [https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_DATA_HUB](http://%20https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_DATA_HUB)